# Having too many connection problem

Tags: mysql, performance, mysql-5.5

We have an magento store and having 9K products and 2 store views the trouble is we are getting too many conection error while the site is in normal loads.

1) We have 100 connectoin open in mysql.
2) We have PhP/apache/Mysql on the same box with 16Gb Ram Quad Core processor.
3) A cron run on each 5 mins for submitting the feed to google and sync with amazon.

Any idea how we can overcome this problem.

Many thanks

Comment: What is the max_connections set to? 
Is it a new problem that you face all of a sudden from already existing application ? Check the time that it takes to complete each cron threads triggered.

Comment: @Mannoj max_connections is set to 100 and its taking around 10 mins to complete cron trigger.

Comment: What is the value of  max_connections variable ? and how many users are connecting you can find this by executing SHOW PROCESSLIST in MySQL.

Comment: @AbdulManaf there are merely 10-15 users are accessing the site but we have an very large query which is creating the records of around 1M in tables and that causing the failure.

Comment: Does SHOW PROCESSLIST show all the other queries waiting behind the large query? If so, blocking is the problem, and the 'too many connections' errors are just a complication.

Answer (score 0):

For time being ensure you have more connections set to `max_connections` globally.

```
SET GLOBAL max_connections = 1024;
```

Consider below points before you conclude anything.

- For every 5 minutes you have a new thread coming so ensure that you have your application efficiency to complete in seconds unless it is really a time consuming process.
- Check what your application does, are they quick and properly indexed for the "where's" you use.

As far as you keep your application idea clearer I don't find any turbulence that you could make.